# java - find an int digit in a string

Tags: java, string, char, int, digit

I am trying to determine whether a specific digit exists in a String, and do something if so.

See code example:

```
String pass = "1457";
int i = 4, j=6;
if( /* pass contains i, which is true*/)
    // ..do something
if( /* pass contains j, which is false*/)
    // ..do something
```

The problem is I can't find the way to do this.
I have tried -

```
pass.indexOf(""+i)!=-1
pass.indexOf((char)(i+48))!=-1
pass.contains(""+i)==true
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `pass.contains(""+i)` works without a problem (no need for `==true` though, the method already returns a boolean). I fact all 3 of your listed tries do exactly what you want them to.

Comment: So does : pass.indexOf((char)(i+48))!=-1

Comment: All approaches should work. There must be some other issue with your if statements or whatever you're doing inside.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I can't find the way to do this. I have tried -any
>   suggestions?

**Code Example :** [(Execution)](https://jdoodle.com/a/oa2)

Here we are creating a pattern and then matching it to the string.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pass = "1457";
        int i = 4, j = 6;

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(".*[4].*"); // creating a regular expression pattern
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(".*[6].*");
        if (p1.matcher(pass).matches()) // if match found
            System.out.println("contains : " + i);
        if (p2.matcher(pass).matches())
            System.out.println("contains : " + j);

    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

**One way to do this is by using Regular Expression :**

A regular expression defines a search pattern for strings. The abbreviation for regular expression is regex. The search pattern can be anything from a simple character, a fixed string or a complex expression containing special characters describing the pattern. The pattern defined by the regex may match one or several times or not at all for a given string.

Regular expressions can be used to search, edit and manipulate text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Integer.toString() to convert integer to string and then find its index in string

Refer code snippet below:-

```
    String pass = "1457";
    int i = 4, j = 6;
    int index = pass.indexOf(Integer.toString(i));
    if (index > -1) // index of i is 1
    {
       //do something
    }
    index = pass.indexOf(Integer.toString(j));
    if(index < 0) // index of j is -1
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pass.chars().anyMatch(c -> c == Integer.toString(i).charAt(0))
```